# Why is my SequenceGenerator skipping id values?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I have the artistId set in the following code:

```
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "artist_sequence",
            sequenceName = "artist_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "artist_sequence"
    )
    private Long artistId;
```

Can someone explain to me why my artistId sometimes skips values and is out of order? What I noticed is that even if I try to insert data into the table that is invalid (when an exception is thrown), that data is also rejected by the table entry, but my artistId will be filled invisibly. This brings me to the following state in my table:

| artist_id | first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Marshall | Mathers |
| 3 | Tupac | Shakur |

As I said, my artistId with value 2 is skipped because I tried to insert the artist that already exists, but I set up that it must be unique. So, the exception is thrown, data is rejected, but my id with value 2 is filled somehow(or it is skipped). Can you guys help me, how can I solve this problem to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty much normal behavior.

The sole responsibility of the sequence generator is to produce distinct integer values, nothing more.

Comment: Is there any way I can avoid or fix this problem, or is it something I shouldn't worry about?

Comment: If all that is needed for id in your design are unique numbers, then you shouldn't be concerned about this.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are using an Oracle database. IDs are generated before the insert, so they are lost if the insert fails. Also when using a  cluster of servers ranges of IDs are dolled out to each server and can vary wildly between consecutive inserts.
Short answer is you cannot rely on IDs being consecutive with no missing values. This could well apply to other databases.

Comment: Does that actually mean that it's completely normal and that it's something that shouldn't bother us? Btw. I'm using MySQL db.

Comment: Yes it is completely normal. Often a timestamp column is added to tables to provide a reliable way to order by insert time.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal db behaviour. Unique id is generated before each insert and incase transaction fails or any other error happens, Id is simply discarded. This is done to not make Id generation process complex.

In short, only purpose of sequence generator is to generate unique Ids, So you should not worry about this

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `@Transactional` annotation from your saving function. For me it solved the issue.

Comment: Please add some detail on why or how this solves it, and where you expect `@Transactional` to be.

Comment: In my case, there is a `@Service` class that (after checking for existence in DB) uses JPARepository's `save()` function to insert records. `@Transactional` annotation seemed to be holding the DB since call thus incrementing the sequence. Having it removed saving works fine and it only holds the DB when there is an insert, so it does not skip ID values.